# Basic CSS issue with image mask

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a figma to html right now. Link : https://www.figma.com/file/X6ailPBDc7C7C2uMohXYuo/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1 The issue is I can't design the 2nd section which is the app screenshot inside a babypink circle. This is my code : https://github.com/Farhatmahi/Weight-Loss-Page Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried an image with `border-radius: 50%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below property to your circle class. This should do the work for you.

```
.circle {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#section-2 .circle` style.

Answer (score 0):

use box-shadow like this it is almost working.

```
#section-2 .circle img{
   box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px  white ;

}
```